# Bundle.getParcelable() and use of generics

Tags: java, android

I made the mistake of passing what I get from `Bundle.getParcelable()` into a non-parcelable pointer, but much to my surprise this was not caught by the compiler. E.g:

```
NotParcelable np = myBundle.getParcelable("key");
```

I looked into the source of the method:

```
   public <T extends Parcelable> T getParcelable(String key) {
        unparcel();
        Object o = mMap.get(key);
        if (o == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return (T) o;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            typeWarning(key, o, "Parcelable", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Two questions:

1. How come the compiler does not detect the error? It somehow ignores the fact that what is returned is a Parcelable (the `<T extends Parcelable>`)?
2. Since the compiler does not detect this, would we not have been better off with a method that did not use generics and plain simply casted the object "o" to a Parcelable and returned it?

Comment: I can't reproduce - do you still see this?